# How to overwrite sass variable of a react library

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, sass

I created a React library and I bundled it with rollup. To define a common theme I used sass variables and I imported them in every components scss(module.scss).
My goal is to make possible to overwrite the theme in every project where the library is used.
For example in my library _variables.scss I have:

```
    $main:red
```

and I want to replace it with green in my new React project

```
$main:green;
```

Is this possible with sass or Should I change the theming with a context API for example.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

See [Sass Default Values](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values).

Normally the *last* time setting a variable overwrites earlier assignments. To avoid loading order issues you can use the `!default` flag to ensure the library value does not override the project's value.

```
// lib_variables.scss
$main: red !default;

// app_variables.scss
$main: green;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Probably sass variables are replaced during bundling operations, so in my app when I use components of my library the value is fixed.